# Office 365 email web app - text-decoration support

Tags: html, css, html-email, office365, text-decorations

So I recently found out that the email web app on Office 365 is not displaying my emails correctly. I have some hypertext links that I have an inline-style setting my text-decoration to none.

```
<a href="http://wwww.example.com" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">
     Click Me!
</a>
```

Outlook 365 seems to be getting rid off all my styles and ends up rapping my link in a font tag like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="//wwww.example.com">
     <font color="white">
          Click Me!
     </font>
</a>
```

Does anyone know how to prevent Office 365 from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it is doing it, but one way to hopefully overwrite this is using the `!important` css declaration in the header:

```
<style>
font, a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Surprised Outlook doesn't include a class in their imposed tags. Instead you'll have to add your own 'un-overwriting' class to all `font` and `a` tags you don't want this overwriting css to take affect on.

Comment: This doesn't work because Office 365 troughs out the header section. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Not very familiar with Office 365... How about putting the style section inside the body? That works for some clients. You could also try adding `!important` inline, but that is a long shot. Otherwise you're probably SOL...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make certain styles work with Office 365:

```
<a href="http://wwww.example.com" style="color:#ffffff;">
    <span style="color:#ffffff;">Click Me!</span>
</a>
```

This example taken from this guide: http://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2014/07/22/office-365-quirks-for-email-designers/

However, `text-decoration:none;` specifically appears to be broken in Office 365: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7553/office365-web-client-quirks-thread/. After testing this significantly I was unable to get it working as well.